# Can I do a purchase system in HTML5 or i need PHP?

Tags: php, database, html, web-applications

Would it be correct to use HTML5 to do following:

1. Select color base
2. Select color top
3. Select color details
4. Purchase

Would I need to use PHP & MySQL? Or can I just use HTML5 and a database?

Comment: You need some sort of back-end system + database. PHP or any other will do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on your purchase solution. If you are using a third party application (PayPal, Google Checkout, etc), then you can develop the front end in HTML5 without PHP/mySQL and link to the appropriate payment gateway/merchant.

You would need PHP/mySQL to do your own payment processing, dynamic product lists, product administration, etc.

**Google Checkout Integration**

https://checkout.google.com/seller/integrate_buynow.html

**PayPal Integration**

https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/howto_overview

Comment: So is better use PHP. I will continue with Joomla! then. Thank you!